# cant grab NSURL components when the scheme doesn't have the double slash

Tags: url, nsurl

I am trying to parse a URL to grab the scheme, path, and parameters using the methods provided in NSURL class reference. I'm noticing however, that if I build the url this way (no double slash after the scheme):

```
NSString *urlString = @"customScheme:myPath?parameter=hello&other_parameter=12";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

I can not grab any of those values from the NSURL. in other words, the methods

```
path
query
```

return nil.

If i add the double slashes like this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"customScheme://myPath?parameter=hello&other_parameter=12";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

everything works fine. Why is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods are very clearly documented in Apple's docs:

> `path`
>   Returns the path of a URL conforming to RFC 1808.
>
> `- (NSString *)path`
>
> The path of the URL, unescaped with the `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method. If the receiver does not conform to RFC 1808, returns `nil`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And RFC 1808 is very clear about what constitutes a valid relative URL:

> `<scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>`

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt

If you want to parse `mailto:` URLs and the like, you'll have to use something other than `NSURL` to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For non-RFC 1808-compliant URLs, you likely want to use `-[NSURL resourceSpecifier]` to retrieve the portion of the URL after the colon. After that it's up to you to break it down into a "path" and "query" if that suits.